# Debugging in ASP doesn't receive remote http requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application and when I debug everything works if I make requests from the same computer (via `localhost:8080`), but it doesn't work if I make a request from another PC.

Is Visual Studio blocking remote requests or is this a network issue?

Because I'm pretty sure network is allowing this kind of request.

Thanks!

Comment: What web server? The standard development server indeed is not accepting non-localhost IP addresses. As does your windows, unless you did configure the firewall accordingly.

Comment: is there a way to configure it? 

idk what web server, it's the default that starts with visual studio when you start debugging. Firewall is off

Comment: Well, yes. It is. And guess what - you should know where. Project properties has that info.

Comment: thanks! solved with iis